# Adding Quality Selector to plyr when using HLS Stream

Tags: javascript, html5-video, http-live-streaming, plyr.js

I am using [**plyr**](https://github.com/sampotts/plyr) as wrapper around HTML5 video tag and using Hls.js to stream my .m3u8 video .

I was going around a lot of issues on plyr to enable quality selectors and came arounf multiple PR's which had this question but was closed saying the implementation is merged, till i came around this [**PR**](https://github.com/sampotts/plyr/issues/1741) which says it's still open, but there was a custom implementation in the Comments which assured that it works . I was trying that implementation locally in order to check if we can add a quality selector but seems like i am missing something/ or the implementation dosent work .

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>HLS Demo</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.plyr.io/3.5.10/plyr.css" />
      <style>
         body {
         max-width: 1024px;
         }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <video preload="none" id="player" autoplay controls crossorigin></video>
      <script src="https://cdn.plyr.io/3.5.10/plyr.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/hls.js/latest/hls.js"></script>
      <script>
         (function () {
          var video = document.querySelector('#player');
          var playerOptions= {
           quality: {
            default: '720',
            options: ['720']
           }
          };
          var player;
           player = new Plyr(video,playerOptions);
          if (Hls.isSupported()) {
           var hls = new Hls();
           hls.loadSource('https://content.jwplatform.com/manifests/vM7nH0Kl.m3u8');
             //hls.loadSource('https://test-streams.mux.dev/x36xhzz/x36xhzz.m3u8');
          hls.attachMedia(video);
          hls.on(Hls.Events.MANIFEST_PARSED,function(event,data) {
  
 // uncomment to see data here 
//                     console.log('levels', hls.levels);  we get data here but not able to see in settings . 
          
           playerOptions.quality = {
            default: hls.levels[hls.levels.length - 1].height,
            options: hls.levels.map((level) => level.height),
            forced: true,
             // Manage quality changes
             onChange: (quality) => {
              console.log('changes',quality);
              hls.levels.forEach((level, levelIndex) => {
               if (level.height === quality) {
                hls.currentLevel = levelIndex;
               }
              });
             }
         };
        });
       }
         
          // Start HLS load on play event
          player.on('play', () => hls.startLoad());
         
          // Handle HLS quality changes
          player.on('qualitychange', () => {
           console.log('changed');
           if (player.currentTime !== 0) {
            hls.startLoad();
           }
          });
         })();
         
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

> The above snippet works please run , but also if you uncomment the
>   line in HLS Manifest you will see we get data in levels and also pass
>   the data to player options but it dosent come up in settings.How can
>   we add a quality selector to plyr when using Hls stream .

Answer (score 8):

I made a lengthy comment about this on github [1].

Working example: https://codepen.io/datlife/pen/dyGoEXo

The main idea to fix this is:

- Configure **Plyr options** properly to allow the switching happen.
- Let *HLS* perform the quality switching, not Plyr. Hence, we only need a single source tag in `video` tag.

```
<video>
  <source 
    type="application/x-mpegURL" 
    <!-- contain all the stream -->
    src="https://bitdash-a.akamaihd.net/content/sintel/hls/playlist.m3u8">
</video>
```

[1] https://github.com/sampotts/plyr/issues/1741#issuecomment-640293554

Comment: How can we do the same thing for mpeg-dash ?