# Setting quality levels to Plyr player with HLS from .m3u8 file

Tags: http-live-streaming, plyr.js

I am using Plyr player with HLS implementation in an angular component, I did all the settings mentioned in the below post

[Adding Quality Selector to plyr when using HLS Stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61300439/adding-quality-selector-to-plyr-when-using-hls-stream/65578854#65578854)

Still, I can't get the quality setting option in UI. Upon clicking gear icon, only speed options with 8 options showing(.75 to 4 ). For the .m3u8 file, even if I set the quality level to player quality option, it won't be showing in UI.

In the console, from player.config.speed attribute i can find the speed options showing in the player UI, but the player.config.quality is showing some in build value like { default: 576, options: [4320, 2880, 2160, 1440, 1080, 720, 576, 480, 360, 240] } same as plyr README.md file

I tried to set the quality level from Hls.Event.Manifest.Parsed event.

Does anybody know how to set quality levels from .m3u8 file to Plyr player? Please help

Comment: did you find the solution?