# how to change video quality in plyr?

Tags: javascript, html, plyr.js

you might say this is a duplicate of

[Adding Quality Selector to plyr when using HLS Stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61300439/adding-quality-selector-to-plyr-when-using-hls-stream)

but its not. my idea is different

what i want to do is when you touch a quality of your preference it will change the source of the player and i want it to be in the player preferably in the menu\settings.

i tried

html

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/hls.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/plyr@3"></script>
  <script src="./script.js"></script>

  <div class="container">
    Try adjust different video quality to see it yourself
    <video controls crossorigin playsinline >
      <source 
        type="application/x-mpegURL" 
        src="https://bitdash-a.akamaihd.net/content/sintel/hls/playlist.m3u8"
      >
    </video>
  </div>
```

js

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  const video = document.querySelector("video");
  const source = video.getElementsByTagName("source")[0].src;
  
  // For more options see: https://github.com/sampotts/plyr/#options
  // captions.update is required for captions to work with hls.js
  const defaultOptions = {};

  if (Hls.isSupported()) {
    // For more Hls.js options, see https://github.com/dailymotion/hls.js
    const hls = new Hls();
    hls.loadSource(source);

    // From the m3u8 playlist, hls parses the manifest and returns
    // all available video qualities. This is important, in this approach,
    // we will have one source on the Plyr player.
    hls.on(Hls.Events.MANIFEST_PARSED, function (event, data) {

      // Transform available levels into an array of integers (height values).
      const availableQualities = hls.levels.map((l) => l.height)

      // Add new qualities to option
      defaultOptions.quality = {
        default: availableQualities[0],
        options: availableQualities,
        // this ensures Plyr to use Hls to update quality level
        forced: true,        
        onChange: (e) => updateQuality(e),
      }

      // Initialize here
      const player = new Plyr(video, defaultOptions);
    });
    hls.attachMedia(video);
    window.hls = hls;
  } else {
    // default options with no quality update in case Hls is not supported
    const player = new Plyr(video, defaultOptions);
  }

  function updateQuality(newQuality) {
    window.hls.levels.forEach((level, levelIndex) => {
      if (level.height === newQuality) {
        console.log("Found quality match with " + newQuality);
        window.hls.currentLevel = levelIndex;
      }
    });
  }
});
```

css

```
.container {
  padding-top: 18vh;
    margin: 20px auto;
    width: 600px;
}
video {
    width: 100%;
}
```

but this is different it doesn't work on some URLs

Comment: So you want to change `default` in `defaultOptions.quality`?

Comment: no i want it to change the source of the player with out it refreshing and the video is the same just the quality is diffrent